# How to implement listeners in unity3d android plugin?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to build a unity 3d android plugin. Although there are a few tutorials on accomplishing this task (including the unity documentation). I could not find/ didn't understand how to implement java event handlers into unity as I am quite new to unity/ android development.

For instance: Obvious things like an AndroidJavaClass Object in Unity can only be used to call static functions took me a while to figure out.

A few resources that might be of help to someone looking at this:
[Creating an android library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYiZZprUNJw),
[Using the android library in unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahGeTNUPLM)

None of these resources were able to help me with the following issue:

**Android Library**

This is an indoor-positioning system (Indoor Atlas), determines the users' position without the use of GPS

```java
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocation;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationListener;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationManager;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationRequest;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IARegion;

public class UnityLocation
        implements IALocationListener, IARegion.Listener{

    // Location Manager requests location updates
    private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
    private Context currentContext;

// These two function will be called from unity to start location services
    public void setContext(Context context)
    {
        currentContext = context;
    }
    public void startLocationServices()
    {
        Log.d("TESTING", "Start Location services function called");
        mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(currentContext);
        final IARegion region = IARegion.floorPlan("1e7d3247-9aab-4de9-903e-aa0fcccd3b45");
        mIALocationManager.setLocation(IALocation.from(region));
        IALocationRequest request = IALocationRequest.create();
        mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(request,this);
    }

// This is the function where the coordinates are retrieved listener
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(IALocation iaLocation) {

        // Log the received coordinates to the console.
        Log.d("LOCATION UPDATE", "LATITUDE: " + iaLocation.getLatitude());
        Log.d("LOCATION UPDATE", "LONGITUDE: " + iaLocation.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

If I call the two functions setContext() and startLocationServices() from any activity in android studio, the coordinates are printed to the console and are updated as I move around the room.

But if I try to call the same two function from a unity script, even though the object is initialised and I can call functions, nothing is printed to the console.

**Unity Script**

```cs
jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
        if(jc == null)
            Debug.Log("unable to get unity activity class");

        jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");


        if (jo == null)
            Debug.Log ("unable to get current activity");
        else {
            Debug.Log ("Current activity read");
        }
        //display.text.text = "UNITY ACTIVITY";
        //location = new double[2] { 0, 0 };

        plugin = new AndroidJavaObject ("edu.deakin.sp9.indooratlaslibrary.UnityLocation");
        if (plugin == null)
            Debug.Log ("unable to get plugin class");
        else
            Debug.Log ("Plugin class retrieved");

        //display.text.text = "Code reached plugin class";
        plugin.Call ("setContext", jo);
        plugin.Call("startLocationServices");
```

---

My guess is that the listener in this case "onLocationChanged" needs to be manually implemented in unity, but I have no idea how this can be done, reading the unity documentation of AndroidJavaProxy was no help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: someone new to java/android programming ... advanced functionality ... yes, I can see how you don't end up with lots of results on that query. It usually goes this way: study the language -> learn how to do advanced systems

Comment: I do understand that I am using incorrect terms here and I apologize for that, I am trying to learn the language by working on a project. How would you suggest I edit the question to make it more appropriate? Thanks

Comment: I wasn't talking about the terminology you used. I was referring to the fact it's pointless to try and implement advanced functionalities unless you have a decent (or strong) grasp about the code you're trying to do it in.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind before starting future projects.